# Why isn't my stylesheet being included in my Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet, coffeescript, assets

I had created a scaffold `users` with all of the attendant views, controllers, stylesheets, etc.
I then *renamed* the contoller, model, DB table, and files to `supporters`.

Everything is working fine, and I'm happy with how it's working except for one thing:
**app/assets/stylesheets/supporters.css.scss is not being loaded with the supporter views.**

All other controllers' stylesheets are loading properly since `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>` is in my application.html.erb file from the rails default.

I renamed the users.js.coffee file to supporters.js.coffee and that is being included. For what it's worth, I deleted the users.css.scss file and then created a new supporters.css.scss file.

Is there anything else I need to do to get the file to load with my `supporters` views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove the `=require_tree` line from the header, and add the line `@import "supporters.css.scss";` immediately after the header, along with similar import statements for other controllers' stylesheets.

I was expecting Rails to do some magic loading up of the right stylesheet depending on what controller was being used. Sass does no such thing.

Answer found [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics).

Answer (score 3):

You have to ensure the following things:

- `supporters.css.scss` should be included in the `stylesheets` directory, not in the `javascripts` directory.
- Your `application.css` file should include the line in the header:

  ```
  *= require supporters
  ```

  This will ensure that the file is included in the resulting combined and compressed `application.css.gz` file.

Comment: Sorry, the file was in the stylesheets directory, and my question is edited to reflect that now.    
I think that my real question is about how the sass files get compiled. Do they all get bundled together into one big final application.css file that the browser sees or separate little css files that should each be loaded by the browser individually depending on what controller is being used?

Comment: That depends on the file `application.css` and the configuration you have set or changed. You should include in your question: head of `application.css` (what is included, what not); configuration of `config/environments/development.rb` and `.../production.rb`. Is the app working in development mode correctly?